# jquery hide checkboxes that have no result in filter

Tags: jquery, filter, categories

i am using the following jquery for a filter with multiple categories.

```
var getFilter = function(category) {
    var filter = $("#filters ." + category + ":checked").map(function() {
        return "." + this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
    filter = (filter.length > 0) ? filter : "*";
    console.log(filter);
    return filter;
}

$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
    var all = $(".filterme");
    var tgts = all.filter(getFilter("brand")).filter(getFilter("class")).filter(getFilter("color"));
    all.not(tgts).hide();
    tgts.show();
});
```

can be seen on: http://jsfiddle.net/ar3PY/2/

Everything works great except that I want to be able to hide the non-relevant checkboxes.
Meaning if I check off "BMW" then "Audi" checkbox should be hidden (unclickable), as well as the other checkboxes that don't exist within that result, like "limousine" and "SUV".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines to the click handler on the `#filters :checkbox` selector:

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
    var all = $(".filterme");
    var tgts = all.filter(getFilter("brand")).filter(getFilter("class")).filter(getFilter("color"));
    all.not(tgts).hide();
    tgts.show();

    var blockSiblings = $(this).is(':checked'); // determine whether or not to disable siblings
    $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('disabled', blockSiblings); // set the property
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ar3PY/18/)

Comment: thanks. but this only disables sibling checkboxes. how can i block the other checkboxes that don't have any answers in the results.

Comment: So if you click `audi` what options should be left for selection?

Comment: compact, limousine and sport should still be available but sport should be hidden. same goes for the colors: silver, blue and red should be available but white should disabled.

Comment: And what governs those selections? Your question seems to only be a part of a larger problem.

Comment: the class of the cars themselves have the values that associate them with the filters. ie. the first car has a class of "filterme Audi Compact silver blue red". Therefore, you know which checkboxes are not relevant. does that make sense?

Comment: in fact it should probably not disable the siblings but just the other checkboxes that are not relevant. a person should be able to choose both BMW and Audi but should only be able to choose the type of car that are relevant with BMW and Audi if those both are checked.